# Install Zerotier on Ubuntu with armhf hardware

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, arm

I have a problem when trying to install zerotier one on Ubuntu which run on armhf board (Orange Pi) using instruction from this site:

```
curl -s https://install.zerotier.com/ | bash
```

But it gives me many errors and finally failed as follows:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://download.zerotier.com/debian/xenial xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zerotier-one

*** Package installation failed! Unfortunately there may not be a package
*** for your architecture or distribution. For the source go to:
*** github.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne
```

I know other people do it and it work with them but I am new in ubnutu.

---

I try to use the repository for Debian Jessie in Ubuntu Xenial on armf:
As first solution and I get an error as follows:

```
orangepi@OrangePI:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.zerotier.com/debian/jessie jessie main #ZeroTier" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zerotier.list'[sudo] password for orangepi: 
orangepi@OrangePI:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.zerotier.com/debian/jessie jessie main #ZeroTier" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zerotier.list'
orangepi@OrangePI:~$ wget -O - 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/master/doc/contact%40zerotier.com.gpg' | sudo apt-key add -
--2017-02-09 15:05:40--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/master/doc/contact%40zerotier.com.gpg
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 151.101.140.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.140.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3175 (3.1K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

- 100%[============================================================================>]   3.10K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-02-09 15:05:41 (7.19 MB/s) - written to stdout [3175/3175]

OK
orangepi@OrangePI:~$ sudo apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
orangepi@OrangePI:~$ sudo apt install zerotier-one
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zerotier-one
orangepi@OrangePI:~$ 

So I try to build the software from source: 
And I get an error also as follows:

  orangepi@OrangePI:~$ sudo apt install git build-essential checkinstall libnatpmp-dev libminiupnpc-dev
[sudo] password for orangepi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra console-data libspeechd2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  minissdpd natpmp-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  checkinstall libminiupnpc-dev libminiupnpc10 libnatpmp-dev libnatpmp1
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
Need to get 183 kB of archives.
After this operation, 720 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 ht..://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe armhf checkinstall armhf 1.6.2-4ubuntu1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err:2 ht..://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf libminiupnpc10 armhf 1.9.20140610-2ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err:3 ht..://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf libminiupnpc-dev armhf 1.9.20140610-2ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err:4 ht..://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf libnatpmp1 armhf 20110808-4
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err:5 ht..://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf libnatpmp-dev armhf 20110808-4
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/c/checkinstall/checkinstall_1.6.2-4ubuntu1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/m/miniupnpc/libminiupnpc10_1.9.20140610-2ubuntu2_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/m/miniupnpc/libminiupnpc-dev_1.9.20140610-2ubuntu2_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libn/libnatpmp/libnatpmp1_20110808-4_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libn/libnatpmp/libnatpmp-dev_20110808-4_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
orangepi@OrangePI:~$
```

In fact I am new to Ubuntu so sorry as I do know about error messages and many thanks to David Foerster as he try to help me.

Comment: Why no one active in this site ??

Comment: We are all volunteers, and answers get answered when someone feels that s/he has the knowledge to do it. Maybe no one answers because they don't understands what your are asking, or because no one here are using the software you are trying to install.

Comment: To chip in on Soren's comment, I find your question clear and well stated and voted for it around the time I answered to it.

Answer (score 1):

So you didn't really read the error message ? If you did, you would know what the problem was.

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://download.zerotier.com/debian/xenial xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

This message tells you that that repository doesn't support your hardware architure 'armhf'. You will have to find an other way to install the software. Maybe ask on a zerotier forum if there are an solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official installation instructions](https://www.zerotier.com/product-one.shtml) ZeroTier One is available for “Intel 32/64-bit (and ARM on Debian/Raspbian)”. I poked around a bit and it looks like you may be able use the repository for Debian Jessie in Ubuntu Xenial on armf:

```sh
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.zerotier.com/debian/jessie jessie main #ZeroTier" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zerotier.list'
wget -O - 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/master/doc/contact%40zerotier.com.gpg' | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zerotier-one
```

---

Alternatively you can try to [build the software from source](https://github.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne#building-from-source):

```sh
sudo apt install git build-essential checkinstall libnatpmp-dev libminiupnpc-dev
git clone git@github.com:zerotier/ZeroTierOne.git
cd ZeroTierOne
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: As you’re a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the “0” at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I'm not supposed to explain the back-story of why, but I've been pushing packages to Launchpad for a project that includes ZeroTier as a dependency: https://launchpad.net/~nerdboy/+archive/ubuntu/embedded/+packages

The .deb packages are for xenial and bionic, and support armhf (as well as arm64, x86_64, and x86).  You can also use the source pkgs and debuild if you need them for other releases (or debian).

Comment: The above PPA now supports focal as well (same 4 arches).